# How to avoid Android Geocoder to return an address without street number?

Tags: android, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

We are currently using the Android Geocoder to get an address from a String.

Then, using Google Geocoder API, we get a Latitude and Longitude.

But there is a particular search 'W 27th St' that returns a Lat and Long, where the address has no street number. So it takes us to a generic point in West 27th Street.

Is there a way to avoid Android Geocoder to consider an address as VALID when there is NO street number?

Comment: This URL from the Google API returns valid results... https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=W%2027th%20St

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. The address is VALID, however, I need the address to include a street number.

The idea is that we are going to meet a person at this address. If we don't have a street number, we don't know where to meet that person.